# If a sphere of diamagnetic substance is freely suspended in a magnetic field will it align itself perpendicularly to the field?

Tags: electromagnetism

Firstly,I have read that if a rod of diamagnetic material is suspended in a magnetic field it rotates and aligns itself perpendicularly to the field. What I don't understand is that why does the rod align itself perpendicularly, why not at any other angle (depending upon its wieght e.g., why doesn't a lighter rod rotate at a greater angle)?
Secondly and lastly, is it applicable for a rod only  or will a sphere or cube of diamagnetic material also exhibit the same behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: spheres can't align in this sense